# Using android devices as wired webcams for computers?

Tags: adb, camera, linux, video

I have got myself a new phone, and I wonder - if I could use it as a webcam.
I know there are WiFi apps to stream video, but:
 1. My Wi-Fi network is slow (1-2 MiB/s max)
 2. The resolution, framarate and bitrate of video form these apps is very limited

Since I can access the device through ADB console via USB connection - I wonder if I could stream the video that way into my Linux PC, to then use it as a webcam in OBS Studio for preview and capture?

I wonder if there are apps that expose the phone as a webcam device that can be fully controlled from a PC (exposure, focus, zoom etc.).

If not - do you think creating such an app is even possible?

I guess hardware H.264 encoding is not a problem on the newer phones (mine is OnePlus 5T), and the webcam interface supports that - so it should even manage to push through 4K 30 FPS video if the bitrate is optimized for USB 2.0 transfer - right?

I'm thining about this, becasue the phone I have capures better video than my Logitech C920 webcam, however with the webcam I can do things I cannot do with the phone:

1. I can store and restore camera settings from PC easily (exposure, focus, zoom, white balance etc.)
2. I can preview the video in realtime on a big screen
3. I can capture it with whatever program I want (mostly OBS Studio)

Would it be possible to expose phones in a way that'd make PCs see them just like webcams so we can use them this way? It doens't have to be wireless.

Comment: you can try creating a hotspot in computer, connect both phone and computer. It'll be fast enough for wifi cam apps

Comment: It might be, but the quality will still suffer.

Comment: I've tried. no quality loss occurred to me

Comment: Can you transmit 1080p 60FPS video? 4K 30 FPS video?
What app have you used?